# Confirm Exit Dialog When Closing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When try to exit the Android Studio, it shows a confirmation dialogue box asking 'Do you really want to exit?'. I mistakenly check the 'Do not ask me again' check box when I tried to exit the android studio. Now, I want that confirmation dialogue box back. I checked it out under File -> Settings but I could not able to find any option to restore that feature back. And also googled it but all in vein.

Comment: I don't suppose it is a registry setting, if it is not in the application?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For **MAC** users follow the following steps:

1)Select `Preferences` from the `Android Studio` menu

2)Scroll down till the `IDE Settings` and select the sub section `General`

3)In the `Startup/Shutdown` section, you will find `Confirm application exit`. Select it to enable it again

4)Press `Apply`

---

For **Windows** users follow the following steps:

1)Select `File` from the toolbar

2)Select `Settings`

3)Scroll down till the `IDE Settings` and select the sub section `General`

4)In the `Startup/Shutdown` section, you will find `Confirm application exit`. Select it to enable it again

5)Press `Apply`

Comment: Mac version differs: `Preferences` >  `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Confirm application exit`

Answer (score 14):

1. Open File -> Settings
2. Enter `exit` in the search box on the top left
3. Click on `System Settings`
4. Check `Confirm application exit`
5. Click on `Apply`

Comment: thanks for the giving the solution for windows users

Comment: @cygery +1 vote for u. you helped me a lot. Thanks (:

Comment: Nice! Best answer for windows!

Answer (score 9):

**1**. Mac <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

**2**. Type "*Confirm application exit*".

**3**. Switch `ON / OFF` in the same windows.

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

1. Go to `Preferences`.
2. Select `System Settings`.
3. Locate the checkbox labeled "`Confirm before exiting the IDE`" and check it.

Answer (score 1):

To enable confirmation exit

File -> settings -> General -> Tick confirm application exit

Answer (score 1):

For updated answer/guide as of Android Studio 2.1.1

1. Go to `File`
2. Select `Settings`
3. Under `Appearance & Behavior`
4. Select `System Settings`
5. Click/Check `Confirm application exit`

Ctrl + Alt + S (for opening Settings shortcut) - Windows

Comment: the accepted answer above is no longer available as of Android Studio 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the above answers, you can prefer the hackish way of altering IDE settings - by editing  `ide.general.xml` settings file (on Windows it shall be `C:\Users\<LOGIN>\.AndroidStudio\config\options` folder) and altering `<option name="confirmExit" value="false" />` to `true` :)