# How to get back "Are you sure you want to exit" dialog back in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

My colleague checked "don't ask again" in the confirmation dialog while closing android studio on my system. how do i get the dialog back? it gets closed by mistake some times

Comment: Check this answer for Mac and Windows instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121532/confirm-exit-dialog-when-closing-android-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is under `settings -> appearance and behaviour -> system settings -> confirm application exit`

Comment: On Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2 it's under:
`settings -> appearance and behaviour -> system settings -> "Confirm before exiting the IDE"` Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation -> When files are created
Choose Show options before adding to version control